# how to change the text color of a table cell based on value

Tags: javascript, html

I tried as follows but it's doing nothing

```js
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
  if (elements[i].innerHTML === "OFF") {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>OFF</td>
    <td>ON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OFF</td>
    <td>ON</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>OFF</td>
    <td>ON</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your code seems to work. Did you run the code AFTER the table is rendered? Or perhaps there are spaces in the cells (use `.trim()`)

Comment: You might want to start at the actual last element, you are off by one `i = elements.length-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image linked  will show how the problem is solved with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3sp5.png)

```js
    var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0;i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerText == "off") {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
    }
    }
```

```html
<table id="table" border>
        <tr><td>on</td><td>off</td></tr>
        <tr><td>off</td><td>on</td></tr>
        <tr><td>off</td><td>on</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) You should not give the image of code. The snippet output makes the output image redundant. So the link is not appropriate. Moreover the code image is wrong, you edited your code since then. PS Please don't **yell**. Proper organization makes most emphasis by font unnecessary. Here there is no need at all for bold.